# Bookmarks in Eclipse, set and go using hotkeys, do they exist?

Tags: java, eclipse

Bookmarks in Eclipse, set and go using hotkeys, do they exist?

Say, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> = Set 1 bookmark

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> = go to the place first bookmark was set

Comment: This is how Embarcadero's IDEs work. I really miss this functionality in Eclipse too :(

Comment: Check the question about anonymous bookmarks: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9752024/1097104

Comment: See (and please accept) the answer from `Pierre Thibault`. Quick Bookmarks allows you to configure bookmarks nearly identical to the fantastic Embarcadero IDE bookmarks...

Comment: Use IntelliJ, because Eclipse is obviously a low-level product in comparison.

Answer (score 39):

Yes. You need to set a shortcut key for `Add Bookmark`. Go to *Window > Preferences > General > Keys* and enter the text filter "bookmark". `Add bookmark` will be listed, select it. Now bind a new shortcut in `Binding`. Make sure that there are no conflicts.

[image: bookmarks]

It may be also a good idea to assign a shortcut to "**Show View (Bookmarks)**" where all your bookmarks are listed. Alternatively this can be enabled via *Window > Show view > Other* (shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>) > and filter to "bookmark".

From here on, you can set new bookmarks. Eclipse will want you to name your bookmarks.

You can navigate these bookmarks, using "Next Annotation" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and "Previous Annotation" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> **but** you need to enable jumping to *bookmarks* first via the dropdown of these two in the annotations toolbar:

[image: annot toolbar]

image source: [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#sourcenavigation_annotations) by vogella

So select any of the two dropdown and enable "Bookmarks":

[image: Bookmarks]

If you don't want other annotations such as Errors and Warnings to be included in the navigation, disable them in the toolbar dropdown for next/previous annotation.

The shortcut for Next/Previous Annotation can also be changed in the Preferences. Their category is `Navigate`, when: `In Windows`, you can filter to their names: `Next` and `Previous`.

Comment: I was wondering, any ideas on how to 'remove' a bookmark via a shortcut key? The "Keys" list offers only the option to make a shortcut for "Add bookmark" but there is no "Remove bookmark" command listed there. I was hoping that simply pressing my new keyboard shortcut for "Add bookmark" would also delete it (ie, act like a toggle), but unfortunately it doesn't work that way).

Answer (score 14):

I was not really satisfy with what Eclipse has to offer. But I found a plugin called Quick Bookmarks. See [Quick Bookmarks](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-bookmarks-plugin#.U9p6nEThGlM). I love it! I can assign a shortcut to a specif bookmark. Just what I needed. It works with every text file.

Comment: This works for Eclipse Mars (4.5). You must first install the Eclipse Marketplace (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285623), replace `juno` with `mars`. Then install `Quick Bookmarks plugin` (1.2.1 and by domui.org at time of writing). Then Window > Preferences > General > Keys and assign `Set Quick Bookmark 1` to `Ctrl+Shift+1` (etc) and `Goto Quick Bookmark 1` to `Ctrl+1` (etc). Now you have Borland-style bookmarks...awesome!

Answer (score 13):

Not exactly.

You can only assign a shortcut to add a new bookmark (like I did in the picture below).
But you can go to the bookmark you have just defined only through the "Bookmarks" View (the second shortcut would only display the Bookmark view)

[image: http://img84.i_mageshack.us/img84/6631/eclipsebookmark.png]

Comment: The annotation preferences (General -> Editors -> Test Editors -> Annotations) has a "Include in the next/previous navigation" which might help.  (Ctrl+, / Ctrl+.)

Answer (score 8):

I personally like these settings:

1. Go to **Window** > **Preferences** > **General** > **Keys**
2. Type "*bookmark*" as the *filter* and select **"Add Bookmark"**
3. Click in the box related to **binding** at the bottom.
4. Erase previously assigned hotkeys with <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd>
   Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
5. Similarly select **"Go to next bookmark"** and assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to
   it.
6. Finally, select **"Toggle Bookmark"** at the bottom, and assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
   <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to it.

This way you can:

- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to **add a bookmark with name** (which is shown if
  you open the Bookmarks view with the name you entered and you can double click on it to go to that line).
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to **add a bookmark without name** (which is also shown in the Bookmarks view but named as "Quick bookmark").
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to **switch between bookmarks** and is very handy if you have a few number of bookmarks.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted except I don't have a key called 'Toggle Bookmark', did you need a plugin for this?

Comment: @user2802557 , There's no need to install a plugin for it. Just follow the instructions. It seems that they've changed the names; instead of "Go to next bookmark" there is "Show in (Bookmarks)" and instead of "Toggle bookmark" there is "Show view (Bookmarks)". Also they don't work as the used to; hitting the keys now just opens the bookmarks page so you can click on them. I don't know the reason. Probably this is a bug for Eclipse.

Comment: I would want the Toggle Bookmark to be able to add or erase a bookmark, seems this functionality doesn't exist.

Comment: You can add the bookmark in the way mentioned in the answer though. For deleting or renaming the bookmark, you can right click on the respective bookmark in the bookmarks view (after pressing Ctrl+B), and then choose delete. Or click on it and edit its name, or double click on it to go to its position.

Comment: I agree with @user2802557, the Eclipse way of handling bookmarks is different to how many other editors work. In editors such as Sublime, there is a very quick workflow between quickly adding bookmarks, navigating through them and quickly removing them again. The provided answer and comments are still correct, just Eclipse doesn't seem to provide that lightweight bookmarks handling.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse 3.5 there are some bookmarks related actions cthat can be linked to key shortcuts:
to bind them you have to go to menu *Window > Preferences > General > Keys* and use the word "bookmark" as filter.

Saluti

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.  You can assign a shortcut to make bookmarks, but I don't think you can specify a hotkey for each individual bookmark you create.

In Eclipse 3.5, if you go to **Windows > Preferences > General > Keys** you'll find the **Add Bookmark** command.  Add a hotkey in that dialog.

Then go to **Window > Show View > Other... > Bookmarks** to display the bookmarks tab.

[image: Eclipse bookmarks tab]

As you would probably expect, double-clicking the entries in the bookmarks tab takes you to the bookmarked line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info: I've got Eclipse Kepler (v4.3) and as mentioned earlier, I've seen a few more bookmark commands available. Of particular interest is the "**Next Bookmark**" command, which is worth binding a keyboard shortcut to. This will work similar to the "**Next Annotation**" command, except only jumps to the bookmarks.

Warning: I've noticed that if you edit a file outside of eclipse and then return back to eclipse, you will have lost all your bookmarks, not nice.