# How do I install Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Classic?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I'm running Eclipse 3.6.1 Classic, which does not come with the Eclipse Marketplace plugin by default. I've looked around the Eclipse website, but I don't see an available plugin for installing Eclipse Marketplace. Am I just not seeing it?

Comment: Any particular reason you cannot just download a distribution which has this plugin?

Comment: It would be much easier for me to just download and install the plugin through Eclipse, since I'm currently using Eclipse on a remote Linux box. It would be a pain to download a new version of Eclipse and copy the right files into the Eclipse directories.

Comment: refer https://www.eclipse.org/mpc/.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

Help → Install new Software → Switch to the Kepler Repository → General Purpose Tools → Marketplace Client

If you use Eclipse Luna SR 1, the released Marketplace contains a bug; you have to install it from the Marketplace update site. This is fixed again in Luna SR 2.

Marketplace update site:

- Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/luna
- Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
- Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
- Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

Comment: Thanks. The problem was when I went to "All Available Sites", the Helios update repository wasn't there, so my searching turned up no results. Adding the Helios Repository then going to General Purpose Tools revealed it.

Comment: Thanks Tom - why these instructions cannot be placed on the marketplace site is beyond me :-/. It may be worth noting that the eclipse update URL for the Helios Repository is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/ - in the standalone version of Adobe ColdFusion Builder 2 which is based on Eclipse 3.6.1, the Helios update repository is not listed.

Comment: FYI: Mine just sat there when I pointed it to the Helios repo.  using the Indigo as described in Subramanya's answer worked great for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly! The new Eclipse Juno is out now, so if you're up to date use the Juno repo instead of Helios.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering the address for Juno repository: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

Comment: This accepted answer also fixes the marketplace in Zend Studio 12, which is essentially Eclipse Luna. Only posting this as it took me some searching to figure it out myself.

Comment: Where in the world are you finding this "help" button? Does it exist in the Linux version or only windows?

Answer (score 97):

The steps below are for Eclipse Indigo Classic Version.

1. Help->Install New Software...
2. Point to Eclipse Indigo Site, If not available add the site
   "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo"
3. Work with the above site
4. Look at "General Purpose Tools"->Marketplace Client
5. After installing, restart Eclipse and you can find Marketplace in "Help->Eclipse Marketplace..."

Comment: +1 Nice step-by-step guide on how to do it. I edit it to fix the numbered list (so it'll be in a list, and not just a long paragraph) and minor grammar fix of the first sentence.

Comment: I tried a modified version for Juno, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno replaced indigo by juno all in small caps and it worked.. :)

Answer (score 16):

1. Help->Install New Software...
2. Point to Eclipse Juno Site, If not available add the site "Juno  - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"
3. Select and expand general purpose tools
4. Select and install Marketplace client

Answer (score 8):

With Eclipse 3.7 Indigo, I found the link at http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/
which told me the download location and plugin was 
http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/indigo/
Which made the "Eclipse Marketplace Client" available in my Software updates after I added that address as a repository. Didn't seem to be in the core list on a fresh install.

Comment: This worked. I just copied the second link of your message into the sites window.

Answer (score 6):

help=>install new software=>workwith choice
Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
and search in the below "**type filter text**"
--------------market

you will see this plugs
Marketplace Client

Answer (score 6):

This is how i managed to install the thing in my indigo

1. Help->Install New Software
2. add this 'http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/indigo/" to the work with field
3. Press enter key
4. choose the marketplace.

follow the steps

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to do it

1. Help-->
   Install New Software
2. In the box type in
   `http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/juno`
3. General Purpose Tools--> Select Eclipse Marketplace checkbox and Finish.

Along with these steps I tried To install the whole bunch of software, but it gives an error later. So please make sure you select only one or two at a time.

Answer (score 2):

first Help then Install new Software then Switch to the Kepler Repository then General Purpose Tools finally Marketplace Client

Comment: You do realize that you pretty much copied the accepted answer TWO years after it was given?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help=>install new software=>workwith choice [kEPLER](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler) and

search in the below "type filter text" --------------market,

1. Select and expand  `general purpose tools` and find `MPC Marketplace Client`
2. Restart After installed..