# Is it possible to download Eclipse Marketplace as a plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I have installed Eclipse SDK, which doesn't come with Eclipse Marketplace. Is it possible to download Eclipse Marketplace as a plugin?

From what it looks from their site, it seems as we can only get it when downloading specific versions of Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

See [How do I install Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285623/how-do-i-install-eclipse-marketplace-in-eclipse-classic)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Classic distribution does not contain the Marketplace client (and that is the only such official distribution). However, it is available for download.

Select Help/Install new software... from the menu, select the Juno update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno), and then look for the Marketplace client - it is in the General Purpose Tools category.