# with Eclipse SDK, how to access to MarketPlace and Gluon Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gluon, eclipse-marketplace

I saw that Marketplace and its plugins are directly available on Eclipse IDE with "Help" Menu (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFLmmFPQYFo).

But, I use Eclipse SDK and this link is not available in its "Help" menu

===> How to drag and drop the Gluon plugin URL from MarketPlace to a Eclipse SDK?

I thought that, in an Eclipse project, I had to write, in the build.gradle, something like that:

"apply plugin: 'http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=2496245'" ,but that does not work. The AndroidInstall, a Gradle task, said:

Failed to apply plugin [id 'http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=2496245']

PLugin with id 'http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=2496245' not found

Note: This URL comes from the "DragToInstall" action on "Install" in https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gluon-plugin

Note:with Eclipse SDK, on "help" menu and, then, "Install new software", if I write in the "Work with" this marketplace URL, Eclipse also says "could not find http://..."

Comment: I think you will have to install the marketplace plugin to install from there see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5285623/2670892

Comment: Perhaps, I have found the solution with Eclipse: "Help" menu - "Install new software" with:  http://download.gluonhq.com/tools/eclipse/release , as mentioned in http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.2.0/#eclipse-plugin