# How can I set anonymous bookmarks in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I say anonymous because, while I've figured out how to set bookmarks, each time a dialogue pops up prompting me to enter a name.

I'd like to set bookmarks like I do in Komodo, where I just press a short-cut key which toggles bookmarks on and off. And then I can use another shortcut to navigate through the shortcuts.

I'm wondering if this feature goes by another name in Eclipse. I'd prefer to set it up without adding a plugin. Is that possible?

---

**I just noticed this question in the sidebar:**

[Bookmarks in Eclipse, set and go using hotkeys, do they exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3141493/1093087)

It's the same question I have. My question is more focused on replicating the behavior rather than necessarily using bookmarks themselves. One of the comments there speaks to that, but the answers themselves are focused more on explaining bookmark usage.

Comment: There is a plugin for this - http://www.etc.to/eclipse_bookmarks_plugin. Do you want to achieve this without a plugin?

Comment: If the plugin accomplishes this and there's no other way, then I'll give it a try. But I'd prefer to do it without one if there is perhaps another feature that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to alter the bookmark creation process without, as @Gangadhar said, a third-party plugin (be aware that the link is for an old version that won't work anymore; follow the link on that page to the new version).

Answer (score 5):

Install the [The DomUI Eclipse plug-in](http://domui.org/wiki/bin/view/Documentation/EclipsePlugin):

- Eclipse > Help > Install new software: Add http://www.domui.org/eclipse-updates/
- Choose Editor Tools

The most important default keys that the plugin sets are:

- Toggle bookmark <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- Next bookmark <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

You can change them in Window > Preferences > General > Keys (hint: filter by "bookmark").